# CA1824: Mark assemblies with NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute (App_GlobalResources.dll for a non-Web Application)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, fxcop

I'm facing the CA1824 warning on my non-web application.

The solution provided by MSDN at the following address applies only to web applications.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385967(v=vs.100).aspx

I've found an alternative solution to the same warning but again it is about web projects (web applications) and not about normal asp.net websites:
[c# warning - Mark assemblies with NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068360/c-sharp-warning-mark-assemblies-with-neutralresourceslanguageattribute)

Is there any way I can resolve this warning for my ASP.net (non-web application) website?

What causes the warning exactly is: 'App_GlobalResources.dll'. It seems that the compiler is creating a single assembly for the website's WebResources.resx located inside the folder App_GlobalResources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A prerequisite to resolve the warning is to convert the website project into a web application project.
Note that Microsoft recommended web applications over websites (See why on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx))

However,  before converting to a web application you should know the differences and the advantages you will lose if you converted a project to a web application. You can find the differences using the same MSDN link above.