# Dotnet Core - Getting a warning ""ark assemblies with NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute"

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am getting the following warning:

```
Warning CA1824  Mark assemblies with NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute  JobsLedger.INITIALISATION
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068360/c-sharp-warning-mark-assemblies-with-neutralresourceslanguageattribute).

However I don't know still, how to add the following or indeed if this is what I need to do..

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en")]
```

Could someone tell me what I need to do to remove this error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this attribute to any file in a project. If you have *Program.cs* or *Startup.cs* then put it there

```
using System;
using System.Resources;

[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en")]

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }

}
```

Or if you want ignore it, add

```
<NoWarn>CA1824</NoWarn>
```

to .csproj file

Comment: I have StartUp.cs I guess I should add it there? - at the top.

Comment: Yes. But in my opinion it would be better to add it to Program.cs